# Recursive compilation using gcc

Tags: gcc, compilation

I am using the `gcc` compiler.

My project source tree looks like somewhat like this

```
test$~: tree .
.
|-- folder
|   |-- hello.cpp 
|   `-- hello.h
`-- main.cpp

1 directory, 3 files
test$~:
```

The file `main.cpp` contains the `main()` function and all the functions invoked by `main.cpp` 
lie in the directory named `folder`

So far in all my little projects I never had to put some source code under a sub-directory.

What I am looking for, in short, is some gcc command for **recursive** compilation in sub-directories and their subdirectories and so on... This command should be invoked from the 
home directory of the code project.

Comment: AFAIK, GCC has no such mechanism.  Typically, this sort of thing is handled by your build system (e.g. Make).

Comment: Interesting idea.  Did you find anything in the manual to hint that it might be possible.  AFAIK, it isn't possible, short of listing all the files on the command line.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler (&& curiousexplorer) I got it working automatically, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59621930/1599699

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't really test it on a c++ library as I don't have one currently, but this should work:

```
find . -type f -iname *.cpp -execdir g++ {} \;
```

I just don't remember what happens when the `-o` option is omitted for gcc. If its necessary then this will at least bring a you a bit closer to a solution. I would recommend using makefiles instead though

Comment: `g++ -o a.out $(find . -type f -iname *.cpp -print)`? It is a bad idea to do it anyhow.

Comment: @VladLazarenko So that will put all compilation data into a.out?

Comment: That should find all files and put into gcc's command line, which will compile them and link into `a.out` binary. If we are speaking bash + linux.

Comment: @user405725 Thanks, I got it working! https://stackoverflow.com/a/59621930/1599699