# How can you compile all cpp files in a directory?

Tags: g++

I have a number of source files in a number of folders.. Is there a way to just compile all of them in one go without having to name them?

I know that I can say

```
g++ -o out *.cpp
```

But when I try

```
g++ -o out *.cpp folder/*.cpp
```

I get an error.

What's the correct way to do this?  I know it's possible with makefiles, but can it be done with just straight g++?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Figured it out! :) I hate the idea of having to use make or a build system just to compile my code, but I wanted to split up my code into subfolders to keep it clean and organized.

Run this (replace RootFolderName (e.g. with `.`) and OutputName):

```
g++ -g $(find RootFolderName -type f -iregex ".*\.cpp") -o OutputName
```

The find command will do a recursive case-insensitive regex search (`-iregex`) for files (`-type f`). Placing this within `$()` will then inject the results into your `g++` call. Beautiful! :)

Of course, make sure you're using the command right; you can always do a test run.

---

For those using Visual Studio Code to compile, I had to do this in the tasks.json `args: []` of a task with `"command": "g++"`:

```
"-g",
"$(find",
"code",
"-type",
"f",
"-iregex",
"'.*\\.cpp')",
"-o",
"program"
```

(Otherwise it would wrap the `$()` all in single quotes.)

---

(Thanks to: user405725 @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/9764119/1599699 comments)

Comment: Funny (as in, funny peculiar) — I hate the idea of not having a build system controlling the compiling and the thought of running the compiler manually rather than having a permanent (and version controlled) record of what files were needed, and which compilation options, and so on makes me queasy.  For all practical purposes, I never run a compiler with the default options — there are essentially invariably a number of extra options needed, for eliciting extra warnings, or controlling dialect, or provide access to external resources (headers, libraries) etc.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It's a one-liner to do all of my compilation, nothing makes me uneasy about that. Having a complicated build system is worse in my view. The one-liner is also version controlled.

Comment: Different eras — different views.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. To compile all cpp files in current folder recursively from vscode, I had to slightly modify the args field in tasks.json file to `["-g", "$(find", "${fileDirname}", "-type", "f", "-iregex", "'.*\\.cpp')", "-o", "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"]`. The key points here being the variables `fileDirname` for current file's parent folder, and `fileBasenameNoExtension` for the name of current file without extension (on windows may need to add the .exe)

Comment: @Alka Yes, that's probably better, and cross-platform I presume. You're welcome to edit it if it works cross-platform. Err... Another answer already has this?

Answer (score 21):

By specifying `folder/*.cpp` you are telling g++ to compile cpp files in `folder`.  That is correct.

What you may be missing is telling the g++ where to locate additional files that those cpp files `#include`.

To do this, tell your compiler to also `include` that directory with `-I` like this:

```
g++ -o out -I ./folder *.cpp folder/*.cpp
```

In some circumstances I have had the compiler forget what was in the root/current directory, so I manually specified it with another `-I` to the current directory `.`

```
g++ -o out -I . -I ./folder *.cpp folder/*.cpp
```

Comment: what if folder has its childs? does it auto included child folders to to compile?

Comment: @TomSawyer No, this method requires you to manually specify individual directories. For a recursive case, a shell script or Makefile would be appropriate for building these entries. Relevant threads: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19738956/can-i-search-directory-and-subdirectories-for-header-files, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510098/g-include-all-usr-include-recursively

Comment: The documentation of VS Code (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc) says:
You can modify your `tasks.json` to build multiple C++ files by using an argument like "${workspaceFolder}\\*.cpp" instead of ${file}.
This website uses the CL compiler, however, and when I try it with g++ it does not seem to work.

Comment: I was using mingw-64 and this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

So I ran across this and saw the vscode task above, and managed a different solution. This will get all the headers and c files from the same directory. Then will work with the F5 key.

tasks.json

```
{
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "label": "C/C++: gcc-7 build active file",
      "command": "/usr/bin/gcc-7",
      "args": [
        "-I",
        "${fileDirname}",
        "-g",
        "${fileDirname}/*.c",
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
      },
      "problemMatcher": [
        "$gcc"
      ],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    }
  ],
  "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case that all files contain their own main and there are not part of the same project/program, you might want to keep their original name and create one executable for each file. If this is the case, you could use `awk`:

```
awk '{n=split(FILENAME, a, "."); outfile=sprintf("%s.out",a[n-1]); command=sprintf("g++ -I . %s -o %s", FILENAME, outfile); system(command); nextfile } ' *.cpp
```

For start, you use `split` to separate filename and extension and store the result into an array `a`. The basename is located at index `n-1` and the extension is at index `n`. So, we change the extension into `.out` and by using `sprintf` store into the `outfile` variable. In the same way, we create the command to be executed by `system` function in a shell.

A shortest version of the above command is:

```
awk '{n=split(FILENAME, a, "."); command=sprintf("g++ -I . %s -o %s.out", FILENAME, a[n-1]); system(command); nextfile } ' *.cpp
```

You could also modify the command to `#include` additional files with `-I` as suggested by @Bit Fracture.

NOTE: This solution doesn't work well if any filename contains a space or multiple dots. Before executing the command, those characters need to be replaced with an underscore for example, as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223182/how-to-replace-spaces-in-all-file-names-with-underscore-in-linux-using-shell-scr):

```
find . -type f -name "* *.cpp" -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0// /_}"' {} \;
```