# g++ -I include all subdirectories with header files

Tags: c++, gcc

I've just stumbled upon [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33662375/how-can-you-compile-all-cpp-files-in-a-directory) about compiling all .cpp files, including those in subdirectories using the linux *find* command:

`g++ -g $(find RootFolderName -type f -iregex ".*\.cpp") -o OutputName`

The problem with this is that all files need their relative path written out when doing #include for this to work. You can get around it by adding what ever directory you need using the `-I` tag:

`g++ -g $(find RootFolderName -type f -iregex ".*\.cpp") -o OutputName -I ./somePath`

But that's still quite a hassle if you have multiple subdirectories. Is it possible to use find again with some other regular expression to include all of the subdirectories?

Comment: _"The problem with this is that all files need their relative path written out ..."_ That's usually intentional. Though you can use `make` in combination with the `find` command and some string substitution in the `Makefile`  to achieve what you want.

Comment: The fact that you're asking for this indicates that your headers are not well organized, you're not using a proper build project or you're trying to save a few chars in your source code in a way that's definetly not recommended. Unless you're just asking this out of curiosity I recommend dealing with the underlying issue instead of using this kind of workaround.

Comment: Things work much better if you list each file explicitly in a Makefile, CMakeLists.txt or other configuration. Using `find` or other wildcards is super buggy.

Comment: @fabian I was just looking for a quick oneliner to compile my project while it's still in the very early stages, Definetely going to use Makefile if i ever start a more serious project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to use find again with some other regular expression to include all of the subdirectories?

Yes it is - some projects, like mbed and arduino, seem to include all possible directories to include paths. In *shell* assuming there are no whitespaces, you could:

```
find . -type f -iname '*.h' -printf "-I%h\n" | sort -u
```

This is error prone to whitespaces in path. When using:

```
command $(stuff)
```

you *will have* problems with spaces in filenames. Research other methods and how to handle whitespaces in shell. Better yet, do not write such stuff manually and reinvent the wheel and move to a build system, like `cmake`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware that I could move to something like `Makefile` but wanted to look around for a workaround as this is a school project i'll never touch again after a week and didn't want to get into the complicated things. The answer was exactly what I was looking for and works for now. Thank you.